# Model Many to Many relations with Abstract Class (error : fields.E331)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I tested this code : https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11760#
but it doesn't work

```
class ClassA(models.Model):
    pass

class AbstractClass(models.Model):
    name = models.ManyToManyField(ClassA, related_name = '%(class)s_name', through = 'ClassA_%(class)s')
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class MyClass(AbstractClass):
    pass

class ClassA_MyClass(models.Model):
    class_a=models.ForeignKey(ClassA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    my_class=models.ForeignKey(MyClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have this error :

```
(fields.E331) Field specifies a many-to-many relation through model 'ClassA_%(class)s', which has not been installed.
```

Comment: Yes, why would you think proposed code in an unmerged ticket would work?

Comment: Who said anything about fusion?

Comment: do you know who is the probleme ?